# PHP Date merging class / method?

Tags: php, data-binding

I am doing work where I get data in various formats from various sources. I will end up with something like this:

```
$dataSource1 = ... ;
$dataSource2 = ... ;
$dataSource3 = ... ;
```

I need to COMBINE these data sources, all with different field names, into one object, that I can sort according to fields, limit to X number etc.... all for display purposes.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a good php library that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions,

You could always create a database and just use that. (Probably the best thing to do)

Alternatively, you could try attempt to do some polymorphisisng? (cant be made into a verb!)

Finally, you could also include all the other pages into the one you will be displaying from.

(I suggest number 1)

Comment: I think I'm one step further. I already have the data in a database. They are individual html pages. I need to grab all pages from site X, and morph it into a compatible object for site Y

Comment: so its across sites, not just across pages of one site? In that case you can send all the information in $_["POST"]

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is using an associative array.

```
$dataSource1 = ...;
$dataSource2 = ...;
...
$dataSourceN = ...;

$data = array()
$data[0] = $dataSource1;
$data[1] = $dataSource2;
```

And so on. Just remember that a numeric index array always starts at 0. So the first element would be $data[0].

If you want a more complex bind you can create a multidimensional array. It means you can sort by specific fields. See an example:

```
$data1 = 'Brazil';
$dataArray = array()
$dataArray[] = array(
                'countryId' => 'id',
                'countryName' => $data1,
                'usersFromThisCountry' => $data1Users
                );
```

Now you can sort $dataArray according to 'countryId','countryName','usersFromThisCountry'.